# How to initialize form additions for jquery methods?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I've got a form where I'm trying to do the sort of thing you often see with tags: there's a textfield for the first tag, and, if you put something into it, a new and similar textfield appears to receive another tag.  And so on.  I've gotten the basics of this working by setting up a jQuery .blur() handler for the textfield: after the value is entered and the user leaves the field, the handler runs and inserts the new field into the form.  The handler is pretty vanilla, something like:

```
$('input.the_field_class').blur(function () { ... });
```

where `.the_field_class` identifies the input field(s) that collect the values.

My problem is that, while the new textfield is happily added to the form after the user enters the first value, the blur handler doesn't fire when the user enters something into the newly-added field and then leaves it.  The first field continues to work properly, but the second one never works.  FWIW, I've watched for and avoided any id and name clashes between the initial and added fields.  I had thought that jQuery would pick up the added textfield, which has the same class markings as the first one, and handle it like the original one, but maybe I'm wrong -- do I need to poke the page or some part of it with some sort of jQuery initialization thing?  Thanks!

Comment: Can you provide a fiddle?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without seeing your code in more of its context, it's hard to know for sure, but my best guess is that you're attaching a handler to the first field, but there is no code that gets called to attach it to the new field. If that's the case, you have a few options, two of which are:

1) In your `blur()` handler, include code to attach the `blur` handler to the newly created field.

2) Use jQuery's [event delegation](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/) to attach a handler to the field container, and listen for `blur` events on any field in the container:

```
<div class="tag-container">
  <input class="the_field_class" /> <!-- initial tag field -->
</div>

<script>
  var $tagContainer = $('.tag-container');
  var createNewField = function() {
    $tagContainer.append($('<input class="the_field_class" />');
  };
  $tagContainer.on('blur', 'input.the_field_class', createNewField());
</script>
```

Which is better will depend on your use case, but I'd guess that the 2nd option will be better for you, since you're unlikely to be dealing with tons of blur events coming from the container.